# Rails 4 asset pipeline in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

My Rails app that I am upgrading to 4.2 from 3.2 has strange behavior in regards to the asset pipeline.

The [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) says to use: `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` which causes this error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: $red: "CC" is not a number for `rgba'
(sass):86
ArgumentError: $red: "CC" is not a number
```

The `--trace` doesn't point to any of my files and odder still is that I don't have any sass files to begin with.

I ran it without the `RAILS_ENV` and it compiled without complaint and everything seems to work.

My app has multiple layouts and themes which made for a slightly more complex and verbose set of asset manifests.

My question is, even though it seems to work is using that rake task without the `RAILS_ENV=production` going to cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are actually sending an incorrect value to the sass compiler. Grep the code for $red or rgba and enter a correct list of numbers for the rgba statement that is causing the error.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Stupid little things...  Thank you very much